# How to Re authenticate a new account in Firebase Deploy Terminal

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I already Logged in to an account using `firebase login` in a React project using VS Code. But now I want to use another account. But it shows I already logged in. Now how to log out and re-login?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firebase logout` to log you out on the cli and type `firebase login` again to relogin. For more command reference, you may check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#admin-commands).